# Array RGB data and put them on Excel automatically

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to array the RGB data for each R,G,B on Excel.

For example, 
convert the images to number data such as

> 10,2,5,3,55,.....,4      R data
>
> 11,33,..................    B data
>
> 22,43,..................      G data

And then, put these data on Excel
The result should be

> R  10 |  2 | 5 | 3 |.....
>
> G  22 | 43 |....
>
> B  11 | 33 |......

(`|4|` means cell on excel)

I want to do it for all images in a folder. 
And save the Excel data for each images.
How can I deal with this problem? Help me.

I use python 3.6.4,OpenCV2,tensorflow,keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenCV image is represented as a `numpy.array` in Python and can be written to a `csv` file as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, csv, glob, os


DIRECTORY_NAME = 'images'

OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = 'pixels.csv'

image_paths = glob.glob(DIRECTORY_NAME + '/*.jpg')


writer = csv.writer(open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'w'))

for image_path in image_paths:

    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    image_name = os.path.basename(image_path)

    (b,g,r) = cv2.split(image)

    rrow = [image_name, str(r.shape[0]), str(r.shape[1]), 'R']
    rrow.extend(r.flatten().astype(str))
    grow = [image_name, str(g.shape[0]), str(g.shape[1]), 'G']
    grow.extend(g.flatten().astype(str))
    brow = [image_name, str(b.shape[0]), str(b.shape[1]), 'B']
    brow.extend(b.flatten().astype(str))

    writer.writerow(rrow)
    writer.writerow(grow)
    writer.writerow(brow)
```

Tested with Python 3.5.2 and OpenCV 4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: thanks a lot! However, jupyter says ---[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/scum_data/divided'---   The DIRECTORY_NAME is D:/data/test,and the OUTPUT_FILE_PATH is D:/data/image_csv. How can I solve this?

Comment: @KTM... Seems like a permissions issue for the notebook. Try executing the code outside of jupyter environment.